# Why isn't apt-cache policy output piped?

Tags: shell, apt, pipe

Cannot get why

```
$ apt-cache policy foo
N: Unable to locate package foo
```

but

```
$ apt-cache policy foo 2>&1 | grep .
```

is empty.

Where in the latter call am I doing the wrong assumption?

The original task: I need to process the `apt-cache policy` output presumably :-)

**UPD**:

`foo` used in my example may be substituted with any package name that **does not exist** in your `apt-get` index.

**UPD 2**:

there is an answer with a workaround. Additional `+50` bounty will be awarded to anyone who explains why the `2>&1` solution does not work.

Comment: `# apt-cache policy vim 2>&1 |grep .
vim:
  Installed: 2:7.4.712-2
  Candidate: 2:7.4.712-2
  Version table:
 *** 2:7.4.712-2 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: What's version of your shell?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh that's right, now try the exact call (package name) I provided :-)

Comment: Because foo package is not installed on your machine.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh so? I'm sorry, but are you sure you have read the question (and the title)?

Comment: `grep .`  == `grep -v ^$`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh not it's not equal (not even close)

Comment: I run `strace apt-cache policy foo 2>&1` and there is a system call `ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0`
I think because of this call 1(stdout) has problems. I mean it is not written to tty anymore

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If stdout is not a tty (i.e. it's a regular file or a pipe) and if no `--quiet` option has been specified, `apt-cache` acts as if you had passed it `--quiet=1`. A workaround is to pass it a `--quiet=0` option.

```
$ apt-cache --quiet=0 policy foo 2>&1 | grep .
N: Unable to locate package foo
```

Comment: `|&` golfs `2>&1 |` :-)

Comment: I can't imagine what the developers of apt-cache were thinking when they decided to do this. Unless they wanted to confuse users, of course. In which case they've done a great job!

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica —quiet is supposed to let you suppress progress messages.  The decision in apt-cache to have it suppress error messages as well might be a bug. I’ll look.

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be some cheaty behavior for redirections in `apt-cache`.
But we can cheat a cheater by *swapping stdout and stderr*!

Try this one, it should work:

```
apt-cache policy foo 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep .
```

Answer (score 8):

If you run `strace  apt-cache policy foo 2>&1` command, you can see the line `ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0`

Because that command manipulates the 1(stdout), 1 is not written to stdout anymore. And if you redirect 2 to 1, you lost both of them.

Edit: Here is a some code sample from apt-cache source code:

```
// Deal with stdout not being a tty
   if (!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) && _config->FindI("quiet", -1) == -1)
      _config->Set("quiet","1");
```

Comment: Okay. Any way to capture them both?

Comment: I could not find any way other than like @Mr_Mig's answer. (Mine was `apt-cache policy foo 1>&2 2>&1 | grep .`)
But I find that in the source code apt apt-cache :)
    // Deal with stdout not being a tty
   if (!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) && _config->FindI("quiet", -1) == -1)
      _config->Set("quiet","1");

Comment: Btw, I also was pointed by someone to the same point in sources just few minutes ago :-) And a potentially better solution `script -c "sudo apt-cache policy foo" | grep Unable` which requires installing a `script` though. As advised - I will put +50 here in 2 days (SE does not let to do it earlier)

Comment: @Esref Your comment about "I find that in the source code apt apt-cache..." should be in the answer, so please add it there. +1. :

Comment: Oh god, there is no +50 bounty option anymore :-(

Answer (score 3):

A "better" solution would be to use a `script` utility:

```
script -c "apt-cache policy foo" /dev/null | grep .
```

That way it intercepts all the output and forwards it to the `stdout`.

The only drawback is that you need to install the `script` if you don't have it yet. In ubunty it's provided by `bsdutils` package.